# capitalisation of 'mum'

Tags: capitalization

Which reference to 'mum' in the following text shouild be capitalised, and which not capitalised? I'm confused...

...................................................................

What? Did you say you’d met a man? Mum…mum – crikey – really? Do tell. What’s he like? Never too late, mum, I’ve always told you that. I’ve also got news, but not as exciting as yours…wow!’
Jessica chose her words carefully. ‘Saffie, it’s not like that, really it isn’t.’ She heard giggles.
‘Come on, mum – what do you mean? You’ve fallen in love, haven’t you – admit it.’ Saffron giggled again.
..........................

Answer (score 1):

When you use 'mum' as if a name or part of a name, it's capitalized. Otherwise, it's only capitalized at the start of a sentence.

> I didn't think my mum would be home.
>
> Why are you home so soon, Mum?

Which means for yours... all of them.

Comment: Thank you - only one of my writing associates and colleagues noticed, the others (10) didn't notice. Hence the query...I thought it might be optional, or old school.

Comment: The same rule incidentally applies to other titles - they get capitalized when used as a name or part of a name. But I think it's mostly something that people who sometimes go by that title notice - my mother would have been less likely to notice your mistake, because her children always called her 'Mom' rather than 'Mum'.